# back button navigation with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I'm building a somewhat gallery app. I use one activity to hold fragment_1 in which I display images in a recyclerview. From fragment_1 I can go to fragment_2. Both fragments have their own different toolbars. My wish is to go from fragment_2 back to fragment_1 by pressing a back arrow in the toolbar.

How I go from fragment_1 to fragment_2:

```
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment2)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

What I already did in fragment_2:

```
Toolbar toolbar = getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_2);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

This didn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `Toolbar` in `Activity` layout or each `Fragment` has its own `Toolbar`?

Comment: each fragment has its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `onOptionsItemSelected` to be triggerd from a fragment you need to set `setHasOptionsMenu` to `true`, for example from `onViewCreated` :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [popBackStack()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()) method from removing fragment from back stack.
Try using this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new fragment1).commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

If each fragment has `Toolbar` in own layout than you can easily access `Toolbar` in `onViewCreated` after `View` is inflated in `onCreateView`. After that you can set the navigation icon and call `setNavigationOnClickListener`. Inside you can choose from couple approaches either to replace exiting `Fragment` by new `Fragment` or `remove` existing `Fragment` or use `popBackStack`. In code that would look like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar) // id of your toolbar 
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp); // set the back arrow in toolbar 

    //set click listener on back arrow
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
 });
```

To use this approach you need to add `Fragment` with no null in `addToBackStack`. For example:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, your fragment here)
        .addToBackStack("BackStack").commit();
```